# Flutter - How to handle status code 302 in POST request?

Tags: http, post, flutter, dart

I am trying to get JSON response (punch-in and punch-out details in JSON format) from the POST request but all i get is **redirect 302 error** and there is no location in the request headers.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:dotp/dotp.dart';

void main() async {

  var client = http.Client();

  var login_url = 'https://test.site.com/index.php/index/loginpopupsave';
  var login_response = await client.post(login_url, body: {'username':'1234','password':'1234@2018'});
  print('Response status: ${login_response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${login_response.body}');

  var otp_url = 'https://test.site.com/index.php/index';
  var otp_response = await client.post(otp_url,  body: {'verfication_code': TOTP("WRELBKVQMDBJDWER").now(),'user_id':'lzpZSd'});
  print('Response status: ${otp_response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${otp_response.body}');

  var time_sheet_url = 'https://test.site.com/index.php/timemanagement/attendance/getemployeeattendance/format/json';
  var time_sheet_res = await client.post(time_sheet_url, body: {'userId': '199','selectedDate':'12-Nov-2019'});
  print('Response status: ${time_sheet_res.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${time_sheet_res.body}');
}
```

[image: JSON response in the network tab]

[image]

Comment: What is really your question?

Comment: I am not getting JSON response in POST rather getting 302 re-direct error.

Comment: What does the response body say?

Comment: Nothing. Just the blank line.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing an exact issue with the HTTP library any solution for this?

Comment: Refer to this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947382/flutter-http-package-post-api-call-return-302-instead-of-200-post-is-success-in?noredirect=1#comment107829289_60947382

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with a `NULL` response using dio package 5.3.2.