# Flutter http Package POST API call return 302 instead of 200, post is success in DB

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

Hi when I make an API post request via **Postman getting the correct status code as 200** but make the same api call with flutter/http package (v0.12.0+4)  or DIO (v3.0.9) package I'm getting status code as 302, but the post was successful and the data was saved on the DB.  how can I get the status 200 for this or is there a better way to handle redirect in post

Found these git hub issues, but no answer on how to fix this 
https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/157

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38413

```
Code making API post
       ........... 

      final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
        final headers = {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        };
        //String jsonBody = jsonEncode(feedRequest.toJsonData());
        String jsonBody = feedRequest.toJsonData();
        print('response.SubmitFeedApiRequest>:' + feedRequest.toJsonData());
        print('jsonBody:>' + jsonBody);

        String url ='https://myapp';

        final response = await http.post(url,
            headers: headers, body: jsonBody, encoding: encoding);

        print('response.statusCode:' + response.statusCode.toString());

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('response.data:' + response.body);
        } else {
          print('send failed');
        }
     ...............
```

Postman Screenshot
[image]

===UPDATED WORKING CODE AS PER @midhun-mp comment

```
 final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: headers, body: jsonBody, encoding: encoding);

    print('response.statusCode:' + response.statusCode.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 302) {
      //print('response.headers:' + response.headers.toString());
      if (response.headers.containsKey("location")) {
        final getResponse = await http.get(response.headers["location"]);
        print('getResponse.statusCode:' + getResponse.statusCode.toString());
        return SubmitFeedApiResponse(success: getResponse.statusCode == 200);
      }
    } else {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       // print('response.data:' + response.body);
        return SubmitFeedApiResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      }
      return SubmitFeedApiResponse(success: false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably that status code is getting returned from your server. Call the same api in postman or any other rest-client and verify the status code. 302 is not an error, it's used for url re-direction. Check with your api developer.

Comment: @midhun-mp postman return 200

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of that postman with response after obscuring the url and other important data ?

Comment: @midhun-mp updated the question with Postman screenshot

Comment: Looking at the posts and reported issues for `http` package, it seems like the redirection for `POST` request not supported. You need to handle it manually, you have to look for http status code 302 as well in your code and the redirect url will be in the header (probably) of that 302 response. Use that url and do a `GET` and you will get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks that did work, I added the code for that if you can please add your solution as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Thank you for updating the working code, it would help many other :)

Comment: In my case, I sent a `POST` API request using `dio` package, which returned an error `302`.

I issued an identical request using Postman, resulting in a successful response with a status code 200. However, when I attempted the same request in Flutter, it produced an error with a returned status code of 302.

I already solved this problem, please check my comment here if you did not solve the problem yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972916/16449728

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 302 is not an error, it's a redirection status code. The http package won't support redirection for POST request.

So you have to manually handle the redirection. In your code you have to add a condition for status code 302 as well. When the status code is 302, look for the redirection url in the response header and do a http GET on that url.

Answer (score 11):

Just add additional header,

```
header : "Accept" : "application/json"
```