# Flutter : 308 Permanent Redirect response. Issue found only on Flutter code. Expected response received on postman

Tags: flutter, redirect, permanent

Below is the response I get while requesting a Post web service via Flutter. When I try the same web service using postman, I get the expected response. What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my code :

```
var params = {
"hostName": 'something',
"username": 'something',
"password": 'something'
}
var postBody = json.encode(params);
var uri = Uri.encodeFull('http://{{api_url}}/account/authenticate');
var response = await http.post(uri, body: postboy, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: " application/json"});
print response.body;
```

Comment: Is "{{api_url}}" a placeholder for a real value, or did you mistakenly copy that from your postman?

Comment: That was not a mistake. I didn't want to reveal the domain. Hence wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment helped me :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60957465/8013132

Below is my modified code :

```
var params = {
    "hostName": 'something',
    "username": 'something',
    "password": 'something'
}
var postBody = json.encode(params);
var uri = Uri.encodeFull('http://{{api_url}}/account/authenticate');
var response = await http.post(uri, body: postBody, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: " application/json"});
print(response.body);

//Here you get the 308 error.

final getResponse =
  await http.post(response.headers["location"], body: postBody, headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
});
print(getResponse.body); //this is the expected response
```